# mysql_fetch_array and while loop accidentally returning every other record

Tags: mysql, arrays, fetch

Question title says it all: I want to loop through every row, but I get only every other row. Funny enough, when I use mysql_num_rows  as can be seen below, it gets the right count. Whats up?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `staff`";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo '<form action="" method="post"><ul>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<li>' . $row['name'] . '
            <select>
                ';
                $i = 1;
                while ($i <= $count) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
                    $i++;
                }'
            </select>
            </li>';
    }
```

Can it be because I am counting as well? I need to count as well. This is a reordering app so I need to be able to change the position of every person, but the options can only be the total number of positions available. Maybe there is a more logical way to do this anyway?

Comment: Your structure is completely wrong. Your nested while loop doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Well help me out then! For every staff record in my database I want to echo a list item as well as a select with the number of options equaling the number of entries in the database. I can see now that there is nothing connecting the select to the staff member but that should be an easy fix

Comment: Its very close, everything works except the fact that I only get half as many list items as I need

Comment: The problem as described in the title is not in the code that you've provided.

Comment: I don't appreciate being demanded to help, when it's of no advantage to me to use my time to help you. Politeness wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: Here's a tip: **STOP USING `mysql_query`**.

Comment: Appreciate all the help... And if you are not here to contribute (stanyer), what is the point in reading the question and replying?? You've managed to post twice without saying anything useful, when if you didn't understand it you could have just skipped the question. Jesus. As I undestand Marcus Adams, my problem is occurring elsewhere... thank you! I will find it. and Yes, Tadman, I will start using mysqli as soon as I finish this project. Makes more sense to me to convert all the functions at once, rather than start right in the middle.

Comment: There appears to be a syntax error (missing `echo` command) after the closing brace of the inner `while` loop.

Comment: That must be a copying error, or the code wouldn't run at all.

Comment: Maybe there's another copying error that's obscuring the reason for the problem. Because I can't see any reason why this code would only show every other row.

Comment: @Eggyal - awesome. If you are into getting those accepted answers, post as an answer and I'll accept that as the correct one. Thanks for spotting that I have been getting tunnel vision looking at it. The problem was I was not echoing the end of my select inputs and therefore the page was no closing it. Don't understand how it reports every other value from this but it makes sense that there would be an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have are not outputting the string that closes the `</select>` tag:

```
                while ($i <= $count) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
                    $i++;
                }'
'//              ^--- NB missing echo
```

As it stands, PHP currently parses the string as a literal expression that performs no operation.

Consequently, your resulting HTML will look like:

```
<li>foo
   <select>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <li>bar
       <select>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <li>baz
           <select>
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
             <option value="3">3</option>
```

How such broken HTML is rendered will depend upon one's browser.  It would appear that your browser is only producing every other select box?

Comment: Good stuff thanks a lot as I said before, cleared that problem up instantly